# fwrite() variable not saving as "$variable"

Tags: php

I am creating a setup system and the user inputs 5 values and those values are set in the file:

```
    $f = fopen('settings.php', 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($f, "<?php $administrationemail = '$administration_email'; $host = '$mysqlhost'; $mysql_user = '$mysqluser'; $mysql_pass = '$mysqlpass'; $db = '$mysqldb'; ?>");
    fclose($f);
```

However no matter what the $administrationemail wont actually show up in the folder.

What I want the file to look like:

```
<?php
$host = '';
$mysql_user = '';
$mysql_pass = '';
$db = '';
$administrationemail = '';
?>
```

What it looks like:

```
<?php $host = ''; $mysql_user = ''; $mysql_pass  = '';  $db = ''; =''; ?>
```

Comment: This is because your variable doesn't hold what you think they do.. Just assign them with what you need/want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use **"** (double quotes) to enclose a string, PHP will replace **$variables** with their value, if possible.  If you add a backslash in front of the variable, like so: **\$variable**, PHP will interpret it as the literal value, not a variable name.

```
$administration_email = 'admin@example.com';
$mysqlhost = 'host';
$mysqluser = 'user';
$mysqlpass = 'pass';
$mysqldb = 'db';

echo "<?php \$administrationemail = '$administration_email'; \$host = '$mysqlhost'; \$mysql_user = '$mysqluser'; \$mysql_pass = '$mysqlpass'; \$db = '$mysqldb'; ?>";
```

I tested it with echo, but it should be fine with fwrite.

If you want line breaks, you may add **\n\r** in the string, like this:

echo str_replace(';',";\n\r","<?php \$administrationemail = '$administration_email'; \$host = '$mysqlhost'; \$mysql_user = '$mysqluser'; \$mysql_pass = '$mysqlpass'; \$db = '$mysqldb'; ?>");

Or you can use heredoc syntax (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).  Note that the backslash is still required on the variables.

```
$config = <<< CONFIG
<?php
\$host = '$mysqlhost';
\$mysql_user = '$mysqluser';
\$mysql_pass = '$mysqlpass';
\$db = '$mysqldb';
\$administrationemail = '$administration_email';
?>
CONFIG;
```

Comment: Thankyou. I never knew a \ would make it thinks as a literal value. However it seems to be only the $administrationemail that doesnt show the rest work fine.

Comment: Check the variable name and contents.